# How to delete a pointer stored within a node?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I'm trying to set up a binary tree comprised of nodes that hold pointers to objects, but in my "clear tree" function I come across a read access violation when trying to free memory at the pointer within the node. Why is there no exception thrown when I free memory at the root pointer, but there is at the int pointer within the node?

Exception thrown: read access violation.
**it** was 0x2.

```
class Tree {
private:
    struct Node {
        int* val = nullptr;
        Node* right = nullptr;
        Node* left = nullptr;
    };
    Node* root = nullptr;

public:
    bool Insert(int* num);
    void Empty();
    bool isEmpty() const;
};

void Tree::Empty()
{
    while (!(root == nullptr)) // Just handling the simplest case for now
    {
        if (root->left == nullptr && root->right == nullptr)
        {
            delete root->val;   // Read access violation 
            delete root;
            root = nullptr;
            break;
        }

        [...]
    }
}

bool Tree::Insert(int* num)
{
    Node* insertion = new Node;
    int* temp = new int(*num);
    insertion->val = temp;

    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = insertion;
        return true;
    }

    Node* c_node = root;

    while (true)
    {
        if (*temp == *c_node->val)
        {
            delete temp;
            delete insertion;
            return false;
        }

        if (*temp > *c_node->val)
        {
            if (c_node->right != nullptr)
            {
                c_node = c_node->right;
                continue;
            }

            c_node->right = insertion;
            return true;
        }

        if (c_node->left != nullptr)
        {
            c_node = c_node->left;
            continue;
        }

        c_node->left = insertion;
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;

    Tree my_tree;

    my_tree.Insert(&a);
    my_tree.Empty();
}
```

I'd appreciate any feedback!

Comment: In order for us to tell you whether it's OK to delete `root->val` you have to show the code that sets `root->val`.  Also, are you sure `root->val` is not null?  It would be good to add an `assert` about that.  You should also show the definition of `isEmpty`.  Really it would be best to provide a [mcve].

Comment: A bit of semantics, but you don't delete the pointer. But you free the memory it points to with operator delete. If root is a pointer to a Node did you allocate it? Or is it just a member of Tree (note in modern C++ new/delete should be used sparingly, but I assume this is part of an assignment)

Comment: Why store a pointer-to-int in the Node when you could just store an int?

Comment: @poisson -- Making `int` a pointer is going overboard and totally unnecessary for the task of "learning about pointers".  The data you want to store is an `int`, not a pointer.  The data structure, in this case a binary tree, is maintained by using pointers, but that has absolutely nothing to do with the data that's stored at the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting with making `Node` responsible for its own content:

```
struct Node {
    Node(int *val) : val(new int(*val)) { }
    int* val = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
    Node* left = nullptr;
    ~Node() { delete val; }
};
```

Having done this, we can simplify the code for `Empty` (and `Insert`) a bit by letting it deal with the value it's storing, so the fragment of `Empty` you've implemented so far ends up something like this:

```cpp
void Tree::Empty()
{
    while (!(root == nullptr)) // Just handling the simplest case for now
    {
        if (root->left == nullptr && root->right == nullptr)
        {
            delete root;
            root = nullptr;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As for making this implementation work for a tree with more than one node, I'd probably do it recursively:

```cpp
void Tree::Empty(Node *node)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        return;

    Empty(node->left);
    Empty(node->right);

    delete node;
}
```

I'd probably also define a dtor for `Tree`, so the user doesn't need to explicitly call `Empty` (in fact, I'd probably make `Empty` private, so the outside world can't call it at all, but that's a separate question).

Comment: Letting Node be responsible for its own allocating and deallocating with the constructor/destructor resolved all access violation exceptions. I really appreciate your time and help.